# Failed DropDownListFor() object reference in Editor Template using ViewModel

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I've been all over SO and the interwebs looking for a resolution to this, and while I've found several posts that get me close, they all end up failing with an "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" error.

I am attempting to create a variant of the "Nested Collection Models in MVC to Add Multiple Phone Numbers" from [Itorian.com](http://www.itorian.com/2013/04/nested-collection-models-in-mvc-to-add.html), but mine involves a little more complexity.

Basically, I've got an MVC 5 EF 6 app which is set up to allow an unlimited number of phone numbers to be associated with any given contact. I'm using a links table to associate Contact ID with Phone ID. The intent is to allow multiple contacts (i.e., family members) to share a single phone number while also allowing one contact to have multiple phone numbers. Phonetype (home, work, cell, etc.) is set from a third table, allowing for dropdown selection. The phonelink table has columns for phonetype_id, phone_id, and contact_id.

I should also probably note that Client extends my base Contact. Phone numbers are associated to Contact, but I'm actually creating a Client to generate the extended fields at the same time. This works perfectly if I don't enter Phones into the mix.

My problem is twofold:

**First:**
I need to figure out what is causing the Object Reference Not Set error on my DropDownListFor

**Second:**
Figuring out how to correctly add the new fields to the view when the Add Phone Number link is clicked. More details on this below.

My model classes, generated from DB by EF:

### Phone.cs

```
public partial class phone
{
    public phone()
    {
        this.phonelinks = new HashSet<phonelink>();
    }

    public int id { get; set; }
    public string phone_number { get; set; }
    public string phone_extension { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<phonelink> phonelinks { get; set; }
}
```

### Phonetype.cs

```
public partial class phonetype
{
    public phonetype()
    {
        this.phonelinks = new HashSet<phonelink>();
    }

    public int id { get; set; }
    public string phone_type { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<phonelink> phonelinks { get; set; }
}
```

### Phonelink.cs

```
public partial class phonelink
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public int contact_id { get; set; }
    public int phone_id { get; set; }
    public int phonetype_id { get; set; }

    public virtual contact contact { get; set; }
    public virtual phone phone { get; set; }
    public virtual phonetype phonetype { get; set; }
}
```

I have also extended phonelink to include a Remove From View helper property (which works as expected via HTML Helpers and JS):

```
public partial class phonelink
{
    public bool remove_from_view { get; set; }
}
```

My Controller for a new Contact (just the GET, as my error occurs before attempting POST)

### ClientsController.cs

```
// GET: Clients/Create
public ActionResult Create()
{
    var viewModel = new ClientCreateViewModel();
    ConfigureCreateViewModel(viewModel);

    return View(viewModel);
}

private void ConfigureCreateViewModel(ClientCreateViewModel model)
{
    model.AllEthnicities = new SelectList(db.ethnicities, "id", "ethnicity1");
    model.AllGenders = new SelectList(db.genders, "id", "gender1");
    model.AllPrefixes = new SelectList(db.prefixes, "id", "prefix1");
    model.AllSuffixes = new SelectList(db.suffixes, "id", "suffix1");
    model.PhoneLinkVM = new PhoneLinkViewModel()
    {
        AllPhoneTypes = new SelectList(db.phonetypes, "id", "phone_type")
    };
}
```

My ViewModel (simplified)

### ClientViewModel.cs

```
public class ClientCreateViewModel
{
    public client Clients { get; set; }
    public PhoneLinkViewModel PhoneLinkVM { get; set; }

    // There are other declarations here for Ethnicities, Gender, etc.
    // They all work for displaying dropdowns, so have been removed for simplicity
}

public class PhoneLinkViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<phonelink> Phonelinks { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> AllPhoneTypes { get; set; }
    public int SelectedPhoneType { get; set; }
    public phonelink phonelink { get; set; }
}
```

And in my View below I call phonelink from an editor template.

### Create.cshtml

```
@* Div for Phone Numbers *@
<div id="phoneNumbers">
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.PhoneLinkVM.phonelink)
</div>
<div class="row top-space">
    <div class="form-group col-md-4 col-xs-12">
        @Html.AddLink("Add Phone Number", "#phoneNumbers", ".phoneNumber", "Phonelinks", typeof(CreateClientViewModel))
    </div>
</div>
```

### Phonelink.cshtml

```
@model TheraLogic.Models.ClientCreateViewModel

@using TheraLogic.Models

<div class="phoneNumber">
    <div class="row top-space">
        @* Phone Number Inputs *@
        <div class="form-group col-md-2">
            <label class="control-label">Phone Number</label>
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.PhoneLinkVM.phonelink.phone.phone_number, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.PhoneLinkVM.phonelink.remove_from_view, new { @class = "mark-for-removal" })
            @Html.RemoveLink("Remove", "div.phoneNumber", "input.mark-for-removal")
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-1">
            <label class="control-label">Extension</label>
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.PhoneLinkVM.phonelink.phone.phone_extension, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-1">
            <label class="control-label">Type</label>
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.PhoneLinkVM.SelectedPhoneType, Model.PhoneLinkVM.AllPhoneTypes, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

If I comment out the @Html.DropDownListFor in the bottom of the editor template, I can view the Create view without error. But with that in place, it produces the Object Reference Not Set error.

The only way I've been able to make it work at all is to add:

```
ViewBag.ThesePhoneTypes = model.PhoneLinkVM.AllPhoneTypes;
```

to the bottom of ConfigureCreateViewModel, and pull it into the view within the editor template with

```
@Html.DropDownList("ThesePhoneTypes")
```

which is more of a workaround than a true solution.

Regarding adding/removing phone numbers when clicking the link, if I use `type(phonelink)` in my @Html.AddLink helper in Create.cshtml, I get an error stating:

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type
>   'phonelink', but this dictionary requires a model item of
>   type 'Models.ClientCreateViewModel'

But if I use `type(ClientCreateViewModel` then rather than getting the content in my Phonelink.cshtml editor template, I just get a set of inputs for the integers declared in my ClientCreateViewModel for SelectedGender, SelectedEthnicity, etc. (omitted in ViewModel code above since they work). I know I need to dig deeper into binding the nested PhoneLinkViewModel, but I'm not sure how to go about it.

### HtmlHelpers.cs

(taken nearly verbatim from the Itorian.com link above)

```
public static class HtmlHelpers
{
    public static IHtmlString RemoveLink(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string linkText, string container, string deleteElement)
    {
        var js = string.Format("javascript:removeNestedForm(this,'{0}','{1}'); return false;", container, deleteElement);
        TagBuilder tb = new TagBuilder("a");
        tb.Attributes.Add("href", "#");
        tb.Attributes.Add("onclick", js);
        tb.InnerHtml = linkText;
        var tag = tb.ToString(TagRenderMode.Normal);
        return MvcHtmlString.Create(tag);
    }

    public static IHtmlString AddLink<TModel>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, string linkText, string container, string counter, string collectionProperty, Type nestedType)
    {
        var ticks = DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks;
        var nestedObject = Activator.CreateInstance(nestedType);
        var partial = htmlHelper.EditorFor(x => nestedObject).ToHtmlString().JsEncode();
        partial = partial.Replace("id=\\\"nestedObject", "id=\\\"" + collectionProperty + "_" + ticks + "_");
        partial = partial.Replace("name=\\\"nestedObject", "name=\\\"" + collectionProperty + "[" + ticks + "]");
        var js = string.Format("javascript:addNestedForm('{0}','{1}','{2}','{3}');return false;", container, counter, ticks, partial);
        TagBuilder tb = new TagBuilder("a");
        tb.Attributes.Add("href", "#");
        tb.Attributes.Add("onclick", js);
        tb.InnerHtml = linkText;
        var tag = tb.ToString(TagRenderMode.Normal);
        return MvcHtmlString.Create(tag);
    }

    private static string JsEncode(this string s)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(s)) return "";
        int i;
        int len = s.Length;
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(len + 4);
        string t;
        for (i = 0; i < len; i += 1)
        {
            char c = s[i];
            switch (c)
            {
                case '>':
                case '"':
                case '\\':
                    sb.Append('\\');
                    sb.Append(c);
                    break;
                case '\b':
                    sb.Append("\\b");
                    break;
                case '\t':
                    sb.Append("\\t");
                    break;
                case '\n':
                    break;
                case '\f':
                    sb.Append("\\f");
                    break;
                case '\r':
                    break;
                default:
                    if (c < ' ')
                    {
                        string tmp = new string(c, 1);
                        t = "000" + int.Parse(tmp, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);
                        sb.Append("\\u" + t.Substring(t.Length - 4));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        sb.Append(c);
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }
        return sb.ToString();
    }
}
```

I can add the Javascript also, if needed, but I think it's ok, as it does add DIVs with fields to the view, just not for type(phonelink) as I need it to.

Comment: you want to avoid using view bags with drop downs.  every time I have run into that error it is because I hadn't initialized the variable.  If you split your initialization does it help?  vm = new vm ,  then on the next line vm.all = new selectlist...

Comment: Yeah, I certainly want to steer clear of ViewBag for this if I can. I tried splitting the initialization in my controller, both with and without Chris's suggestion below in place in my ViewModel. All variations still produce the same "Obj Ref not set" result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although it doesn't really answer the question of why the dropdownlistfor was failing from within the editor template, I have achieved a solution for my project.

I ditched the editor template altogether, and am now rendering the PhoneLink div as a partial instead. I just decided to use an alternative method for adding additional phone links, which negates the need for a phonelink editor template in my case.

When I changed `@Html.EditorFor(model => model.PhoneLinkVM.phonelink)` to `@Html.Partial("_PhonelinkPartial", Model.PhoneLinkPartial)` (along with moving/renaming a few related files) my view rendered as anticipated.

I will handle the "Add Phone Number" functionality with JQuery and modal popups instead.

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize `PhoneLinkVM`. This doesn't cause a problem with calls to other HtmlHelpers because the expression you pass as the first param is not actually evaluated. However, the select list parameter passed to `DropDownListFor` is a straight-up variable reference, and by default `PhoneLinkVM` is null.

To fix it you just need to add a constructor like the following to your view model:

```
public class ClientCreateViewModel
{
    public ClientCreateViewModel()
    {
        PhoneLinkVM = new PhoneLinkViewModel();
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.  I thought PhoneLinkVM would be initialized in my controller when I called `ConfigureCreateViewModel` which initializes `AllPhoneTypes` to a new SelectList.

I tried adding the constructor above to the VM, but it produces the same "Obj Ref not set" result.

I also tried leaving the constructor in place while testing Matt's suggestion of splitting the initialization of `AllPhoneTypes` in the controller, but still the same outcome.